# What is the finder's default midi player and how does it know which instrument to associate with tracks?

Tags: finder, audio, mediaplayer, midi

What is the finder's default midi player and how does it know which instrument to associate with tracks?

Also where does it take those instruments from? A VST? Is it possible to use these sounds someone with another program like a digital audio interface?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Quick Look, it uses Audio.qlgenerator:

```
$ qlmanage -m plugins|grep midi
  public.midi-audio -> /System/Library/QuickLook/Audio.qlgenerator (555.5 - loaded)
```

Information about what instruments tracks use is part of .mid files. .mid files predate the VST format, but there are 128 instruments defined by [General MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI) and the sounds for them are usually synthesized from wavetables in soundfont (sf2) or DLS files. In earlier versions of OS X you could [change the soundfont from System Preferences](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021001054536507), but [it's much more difficult now](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/is-it-possible-to-modify-os-x-default-midi-sounds).

If you want to use .mid style sounds in a DAW, there's the DLSMusicDevice AU:

[image]

In Live you can change the sound by changing the program and playing at least one note from a clip:

[image]

Comment: is there an alternative to DLSMusicDevice AU, it makes my ableton live crash and multiple tracks seem to have problems playing at the same time.